# Does user required DDL permissions for hibernate schema validation

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I have upgraded hibernate to `5.1.17`. I am trying start application with a user who does not have DDL permissions(with `DML` and `select` privileges) but server start up is failing with `Schema-validation: missing table`.

Are there any changes in hibernate upgrade related to user permissions for schema validation?
It was working fine earlier. 
Below are details about application:

```
server: tomcat
hibernate version: 5.1.17
spring version: 4.3.20
DB: Oracle
```

Please let me know any other information required.

EDIT: using data-source-ApplicationContext.xml

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="${datasource.class.name}"
          destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" p:user="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" p:initialPoolSize="${datasource.initial-pool-size}" p:maxPoolSize="${datasource.max-pool-size}"
          p:acquireRetryAttempts="5" p:acquireRetryDelay="3000"
          p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="300"
          p:debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true"
          p:maxAdministrativeTaskTime="600"
          p:numHelperThreads="5"
          p:testConnectionOnCheckout="${test.connection.on.checkout:false}">
    </bean>
```

Comment: Nope. But you are using oracle and you probably need to enable the synonyms to be available on the connection. Or your schema simply doesn't match what there is in your entity (hence the error). But I suspect that it it related to the connection synonyms feature not being enabled.

Comment: I am able to query the table with that user. Could you elaborate about enable synonyms point, it seems like relevant for my case? We also have synonyms.

Comment: Set the connection property for synonyms to true (and tell hibernate to use them). However how to do that depends on which connection pool/datasource you are using, what you use for hibernate (plain hibernate or JPA and the latter with or without a `persistence.xml`). Or if you use a JNDI based connection in tomcat. So currently there is a bit too little information to give a detailed answer.

Comment: I am not aware of these things. I will try to provide as much as I can. Please check my edit